# Dynamic form field creation with increment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Following is my piece of code which I am using to create dynamic forms by click "Add more..." button. My question is how can I add +1 on the dynamically generate fields so their names should look like `testimonial1`, `testimonial2`, `testimonial3` and so on.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8xcs1xcc/).

HTML:

```
<ul id="testimonial_ul" style="list-style-type: none; padding-left: 0px;">
    <li>
        <div class="field">
            <input title="Testimonial" name="testimonial" class="testimonial required" type="text" placeholder="Testimonial"/>
            <input name="testimonial_by" id="testimonial_by" class="testimonial_by required" type="text" placeholder="by..."/>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
<a href="#" id="more_testimonials">Add more...</a>
```

JS:

```
$("#more_testimonials").click(function() {
    $("#testimonial_ul").append('<li><div class="field"><input class="testimonial" type="text" placeholder="Testimonial"/><input class="testimonial_by" type="text" placeholder="by..."/></div><a class="removeLI">Remove</a></li> ');
});
```

Comment: Fiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net/8xcs1xcc/

Comment: set a counter outside the function. http://jsfiddle.net/8xcs1xcc/1/

Comment: I would strongly recommend to look at knockoutjs or other templating framework. It will make this task much simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your fiddle [CHECK HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/go4vaibhav/8xcs1xcc/5/)

```
var formInputLen = $('.testimonial').length;
```

Calculate the total elements with class `testimonial`. And add the incremented counter to the id `id="testimonial' + (formInputLen + 1) +'"`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var counter = 1;
$("#more_testimonials").click(function () {
    $("#testimonial_ul").append('<li><div class="field"><input  name="Testimonial'+counter+'" class="testimonial" type="text" placeholder="Testimonial"/><input name="Testimonial'+counter+'" class="testimonial_by" type="text" placeholder="by..."/></div><a class="removeLI">Remove</a></li> ');
    counter++;
});
```

Working [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/AmanVirdi/8xcs1xcc/6/)

Answer (score -1):

You can replace some special string to number of inputs.
http://fiddle.jshell.net/k1twc1tz/1/